# In jQuery Isotope or Masonry, can I ignore an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, masonry

I have this list of items I want to filter through:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="item filter">This is where I'd put my filters</li>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

So then I want to execute it like so...

```
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item'
  });
```

...but I want an option like `ignore: '.filter'`. Is something like that doable?

The whole goal is to put the filters inside the container, taking on the same styles and transitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item:not(.filter)'
});
```

Simply use the `:not()` selector.

**EDIT:**

You suggest wanting to include it in the initial isotope selection, and for it to act as an item of the isotope, except not be *filterable* - at least this is how I am understanding you.
So to achieve this, keep your original:

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item'
});
```

And later, when you do your filters, simply always include `, .filter`
Example:

```
//Assume something got clicked, which had a data-filter attribute.
var filters = $(this).data('filter');
$container.isotope({
    filter: filters +', .filter'
});
```

Comment: That almost works. The functionality and markup end up correct, but the CSS positioning ends up ignoring that the `.filter` item even exists and it displays underneath all the other items.

Comment: So what do you want to *ignore* it from then? Being able to be filtered?

Comment: Yes. It should never disappear, but it has to use the `.item` class in order to inherit all of the animation and resizing features.

Comment: It was including the `.filter` / "always on" class that got me. Initially it seems a bit hacky, but once implemented it makes sense. Thanks folks :)